# Count users from table 2 in request to table 1

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have table with positions

```
tbl_positions
   id position
    1 Driver
    2 Lobby
    3 Support
    4 Constructor
```

and in other table i have users

```
tbl_workers
  id   name   position status
   1   John   2        3
   2   Mike   3        2
   3   Kate   2        3
   4   Andy   1        0
```

i do request of positions

Without status I select everything with this query .

```
SELECT p.id, p.position, count(*) FROM  tbl_positions as p
inner join tbl_workers as w on w.position=p.id
group by p.id, p.position
```

But now i need output same query but also considers status, status 2=booked status, 3=placed. I need output like this in single query.

```
Position    booked placed
Driver        0       0
Lobby         0       2
Support       1       0
Constructor   0       0
```

I tried add WHERE `tbl_workers.status IN (2)` for booked and `WHERE tbl_workers.status IN (3)` for placed and it works in two queries, but no luck joining this into one query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id, 
    p.position, 
    SUM(CASE w.Status WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS booked,
    SUM(CASE w.Status WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS placed
  FROM  tbl_positions AS p LEFT JOIN tbl_workers AS w 
      ON w.position=p.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.position
```

Comment: You forgot END after each 0. But the solution is excellent, thank you.
Is there way to supplay multiple value like WHEN (3,4,6) THEN 1 ELSE 0...?

Comment: AFAIK you can't do it like `WHEN(3,4,6)`. You can still use an OR conditon like `CASE WHEN ( w.Status = 2 OR w.Status = 4)` etc

Comment: Thanks, also important point how i make it show "Constructor" position now it does only show ones that have people booked or placed , not all.

Comment: @MrWhddite33: Make the join a left join. Updated the post. Pls chk

Comment: If we imagine that under my_positions there's position_two how would request look like?

Comment: I did not get what you are asking for?

Comment: Pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537381/cound-data-from-multiple-tables-using-sum

Answer (score 0):

Although you *can* do this with a single SQL query, it may be more *straightforward* to handle this using PHP.

Use your current query and add `status` to the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT p.id, p.position, w.status, count(*) FROM  tbl_positions as p
inner join tbl_workers as w on w.position=p.id
group by p.id, p.position, w.status
```

You'll get a result set like this:

```
position    status  count
Driver        2       0
Lobby         2       0
Support       2       1
Constructor   2       0
Driver        3       0
Lobby         3       2
Support       3       0
Constructor   3       0
```

Use PHP to logically determine `2 = booked` and `3 = placed`.