# Count data from multiple tables using SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have table with positions

```
tbl_positions
   id position
    1 Driver
    2 Lobby
    3 Support
    4 Constructor
```

and in other table i have users

EDIT:

```
   tbl_workers
      id   name   position position2 status
       1   John   2        3         4
       2   Mike   3        2         2
       3   Kate   2        0         3
       4   Andy   1        0         0
```

i do request of positions

```
SELECT p.id, 
    p.position, 
    SUM(CASE w.Status WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS booked,
    SUM(CASE w.Status WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS placed
  FROM  tbl_positions AS p LEFT JOIN tbl_workers AS w 
      ON w.position=p.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.position
```

I need output like this in single query.

```
Position    booked placed
Driver        0       0
Lobby         1       2
Support       0       2
Constructor   0       0
```

I need to evalate both field positon1 and position2 instead of one. I think its easy to modify it but i cannot find the right solution please help.

EDIT : Added status 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of joining to `tbl_workers` you could join to its unpivoted variation where `position` and `position2` would be in the same column but in different rows.

Here's how the unpivoting might look like:

```
SELECT
  w.id,
  w.name,
  CASE x.pos WHEN 1 THEN w.position ELSE w.position2 END AS position,
  w.status
FROM tbl_workers AS w
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS pos UNION ALL SELECT 2) AS x
```

Here's the entire query, which is basically your original query with the above query substituting for the `tbl_workers` table:

```
SELECT p.id, 
  p.position, 
  SUM(CASE w.Status WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS booked,
  SUM(CASE w.Status WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS placed
FROM tbl_positions AS p
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      w.id,
      w.name,
      CASE x.pos WHEN 1 THEN w.position ELSE w.position2 END AS position,
      w.status
    FROM tbl_workers AS w
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS pos UNION ALL SELECT 2) AS x
  ) AS w 
  ON w.position=p.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.position
```

---

**UPDATE**

This is a modified script according to additional request in comments:

```
SELECT p.id, 
  p.position, 
  SUM(CASE w.Status WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS booked,
  SUM(CASE w.Status WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS placed
FROM tbl_positions AS p
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      w.id,
      w.name,
      CASE x.pos WHEN 1 THEN w.position ELSE w.position2 END AS position,
      CASE w.status
        WHEN 4 THEN CASE x.pos WHEN 1 THEN 3 ELSE 2 END
        ELSE w.status
      END AS status
    FROM tbl_workers AS w
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS pos UNION ALL SELECT 2) AS x
  ) AS w 
  ON w.position=p.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.position
```

The idea is to substitute the `4` status in the subselect with `3` or `2` depending on whether we are currently to pull `position` or `position2` as the unified `position`. The outer select keeps using the same logic as before.

Comment: Thanks, but i forgot to mention status 4 on workers table if this status used then position is placed and position2 is booked can you modify your answer to correctly process this please?

Answer (score 0):

not really sure what you mean by "evaluate both fields" - but here is an example on how to sum up both:

```
SELECT
P.ID,
P.POSITION,
((SELECT SUM (CASE W.STATUS WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM TBL_WORKERS W WHERE W.POSITION = P.ID) + (SELECT SUM (CASE W.STATUS WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM TBL_WORKERS W WHERE W.POSITION2 = P.ID)) AS BOOKED,
((SELECT SUM (CASE W.STATUS WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM TBL_WORKERS W WHERE W.POSITION = P.ID) + (SELECT SUM (CASE W.STATUS WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM TBL_WORKERS W WHERE W.POSITION2 = P.ID)) AS PLACED
FROM TBL_POSITIONS P
```

Answer (score 0):

since your data is not normalized (ie: two columns both representing a position in a single row), I would do a UNION of the workers first, then apply your outer count/group by... something like...  Each part of the inner query is pre-aggregating and only counting for the records qualifying the status 2 or 3 and have a position.  So, if you have a large table, it would be more noticeable for performance.    Then, that result gets summed at the outer level for all possible positions using COALESCE() to prevent NULL values in your output result.

```
SELECT 
      p.id,
      p.position, 
      coalesce( SUM(w.Booked), 0 )  AS booked,
      coalesce( SUM(w.Placed), 0 )  AS placed
   FROM  
      tbl_positions AS p 
         LEFT JOIN 
            ( select w1.Position as PositionID,
                     sum( if( w1.status = 2, 1, 0 )) as Booked,
                     sum( if( w1.status = 3, 1, 0 )) as Placed
                 from 
                     tbl_workers w1
                 where
                         w1.status in ( 2, 3 )
                     and w1.Position > 0
                 group by 
                     PositionID
              union all
              select w2.Position2 as PositionID,
                     sum( if( w2.status = 2, 1, 0 )) as Booked,
                     sum( if( w2.status = 3, 1, 0 )) as Placed
                 from
                     tbl_workers w2
                 where
                         w2.status in ( 2, 3 )
                     and w2.Position2 > 0
                 group by 
                     PositionID ) as w
        on p.id = w.positionID
   group by
       p.id,
       p.position
```